# Display SQLite query result in Listview in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, azure-mobile-services

In my Android app I have an activity with a listview that displays about 4000 items that are stored 
locally in a SQLite Database. If I make an edit to an item, how can I get only this change in the listview,
without having to refresh all the item list (which means a new query for 4000 results)? This query slows down the performance.

I would like something like NSFetchedResultsController of ios.

Answer (score 2):

Strategy should be -

1. As you are editing the contact, if the update is successful you just fetch the latest info from db for this specific contact only.
2. Update the edited contact object in your adapter's source List/Array's specific position.
3. Invoke your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. In your ways, i will have to keep the arrayList (that is passed in the Adapter), continuesly updated with the changes that happen to the Database. That's exactly how i thought of it, but is there a more efficient way to implement it?

Comment: This approach is the being used with above 10k rows of some of our live apps. So far served our needs very well. now "better","more efficient" is always a subjective question. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. you must have an id for each contact in your SQL lite database.
2. when you edit a contact update that specific record in your database on basis of the id.
3. if update is successfull means the information you sent to database is stored successfully .
4. now you can use the same informtion to update your ArrayList/HashMap whatever you are using to populate your listview. 
   Ex:- suppose you edited 3rd index contact in your listview on successfull update you add like yourarraylist.add(3,contact);
5. and the fire notifydatasetChanged.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps if possible:

1. Try to fetch the data from db, but do it in different thread which won't effect the main UIThread.
2. Then you can call the **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** on adapter object. It will do the job i hope :).